# How to resolve missing Lua DLL when using LuaBinaries and LuaBridge?

Tags: c++, dll, lua, luabridge

I'm trying to embed Lua into C++ (and learn Lua), starting off with Elias Daler's training wheels method [here](https://eliasdaler.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/using-lua-with-cpp-luabridge/). I'm using MSVC 14.0, LuaBinaries 5.3.2 - Release 1 (specifically, lua-5.3.2_Win32_dllw4_lib.zip [here](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html)), and LuaBridge 2.0.

I've added the following Additional Include Directories:

> C:\lua-5.3.2_Win32_dllw4_lib\include;C:\LuaBridge

And the following Additional Dependency:

> C:\lua-5.3.2_Win32_dllw4_lib\liblua53.a

And I'm using the following source (pared down as far as it can):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <LuaBridge.h>

int main() {
    luabridge::lua_State* L = luabridge::luaL_newstate();
}
```

That source compiles and links fine, but the application itself causes a standard missing DLL system error:

> The program can't start because lua53.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

lua53.dll is in C:\lua-5.3.2_Win32_dllw4_lib\ —what am I missing?

Comment: You are linking libraries for MinGW. You should use msvc14 version with "dll14" postfix. All the versions are here: [click](https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.3.2/Windows%20Libraries/Dynamic/)

Comment: Much appreciated; I hadn't seen that! Out of curiosity, what sorts of problems would I have run into with the MinGW version? Everything I've tested in the last 5 minutes has run identically with the MinGW and msvc14 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx), Windows searches for DLLs in the following directories:

> 1. The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
> 2. The current directory.
> 3. The Windows system directory. The `GetSystemDirectory` function retrieves the path of this directory.
> 4. The Windows directory. The `GetWindowsDirectory` function retrieves the path of this directory.
> 5. The directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable.

So, one way to solve the problem would be to add `C:\lua-5.3.2_Win32_dllw4_lib` to the current user's `PATH`.

Compared to the other options, this has the advantages of not requiring admin privileges and not requiring `lua53.dll` to be in either the current directory or the same directory as your executable.